# Is it possible to use UG on Windows?

Tags: scip

Is it possible to use the [UG framework](http://ug.zib.de) as an external library on Windows? I'd guess that ug[SCIP,Pthreads] would not be possible on Windows, but maybe ug[SCIP,MPI]?

I checked the ug readme and the articles for ParaSCIP and FiberSCIP, but did not get any information about Windows compatibility. Also, the precompiled libraries in the site do not seem to have ug, and the Optimization Suite seems to only work on Linux.

Comment: Well, it's definitely *possible*. It's simply a matter of whether you're able to compile it on Windows. It might require some manual steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have tried FiberSCIP on Windows 64bits. It requires pthread-w32 & works fine so far.